To what extent is it acceptable academic practice to ask for help in SE to write a proof of a paper that may be published?
I am currently trying to write a mathematical proof for a paper that I hope will some day be published in some peer-reviewed journal. In said proof, there is a step I am not seeing, and I have been pondering the possibility of asking for help in https//:math.staxckexchange.com. However, I am not sure whether this could contravene good academic practice, prevent me from publishing the paper, or prevent me from claiming it is a solo-authored paper.
Hence, can I ask for help in SE for a paper I expect to publish? If yes, are there any good etiquette rules I should follow?
